# Computer readable list of human names / phone directory?

Tags: apache-flex, language-agnostic, spell-checking

I'm trying to compile a decent .zwl file for squiggly spell checking in Flex; using British words, not American as supplied by default.

Ive managed to create a decent British list of words and ran them through the AdobeSpellingGen app to get a .zwl; great stuff.

However i need to add into this list a list of names, so they wont be flagged.

Does anyone know of a good source of either free, or paid for list of English Fore and surnames? Im trying BT as i type :)

Thanks, any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of baby names sites out there. This might be a good one http://www.listofbabynames.org/a_boys.htm as it would be fairly easy to copy.

I'll keep looking

Comment: Thanks Mark.

Thats where i started buy we need it to be a bit more comprehensive. Ive tried the national office for statics / census office but no dice. Still on hold at BT.

Comment: This one looks good http://www.gro-scotland.gov.uk/files1/stats/pop-names-07-t4.csv

Comment: Here is a big list of surnames http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/data/surnames.csv

google "names filetype:csv" or "surnames filetype:csv" is a good source :D

Comment: filetype:xls is worth a shot too

http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=3&ved=0CA4QFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.census.gov%2Fgenealogy%2Fwww%2FTop1000.xls&ei=pqz8SreEOIjp4QbG4e38Bg&usg=AFQjCNF0OvvMqIv5fH9E3Ymd1hzp0W_ZKQ&sig2=nK0VdagZTaLcS8bevjAPxA - has the top 1000 family names from the census

Answer (score 1):

You can screen scrape http://www.britishsurnames.co.uk/browse for a list of surnames.  I'm not sure where you'd find first names though.

Answer (score 1):

gnu aspell has spell checking for common names. You can try it out here:

http://chxo.com/scripts/spellcheck.php?showsource=1

source is here: http://aspell.net/

i'm not too familiar with it though so i couldn't tell you how to extract the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

The US Census site has a list of >150k first names and surnames from the 1990 and 2000 censuses, at

http://www.census.gov/genealogy/www/

Of course, these aren't UK names, but might do if you can't find anything better.